# Background process terminated with code 1.Failed to calculate Effective POM. Please check output window 'Maven for Java' for more details

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Background process terminated with code 1.

Not able to run the selenium driver and whenever saving the added dependencies it shows the above 2 errors.
I want to automate a website using the maven bcoz when runnig the program it is always showing .
Unable to establish websocket connection